# How to rename values in a column from list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
col1       col2
value      test1
value      test2
value      test3
value      test4
value      test5
```

I want to rename col1 from a list in a repeating fashion like so:

```
lst = ['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5']

col1       col2
new1      test1
new2      test2
new3      test3
new4      test4
new5      test5
```

I need the list to repeat for all the rows in col1.

I tried this:

```
df = df.set_index('col1')
df = df.rename(index={'value':['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5']})
```

but this passes the entire list into each row of col1 like so:

```
col1                                      col2
['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5']      test1
['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5']      test2
['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5']      test3
['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5']      test4
['new1','new2','new3','new4','new5']      test5
```

Comment: your list have the same lenght of DF?

Comment: @Terry no, my df 2000 rows where I want to replace `value` with the elements in the list. So every 5 `'values'` I want to replace with the new column names. and keep repeating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `assign`

This only works for OP's example where the `lst` length is the same as the dataframe `df`

```
df.assign(col1=lst)

   col1   col2
0  new1  test1
1  new2  test2
2  new3  test3
3  new4  test4
4  new5  test5
```

---

### More generically

This is more generic.  If you aren't using Python 3.6 and have f-strings you can use `str.format`

```
df.assign(col1=[f'new{i+1}' for i in range(len(df))])
# df.assign(col1=[*map('new{}'.format, range(1, len(df) + 1))])

   col1   col2
0  new1  test1
1  new2  test2
2  new3  test3
3  new4  test4
4  new5  test5
```

---

### With `itertools`

If you want to just repeat the list you've got, I'd use `itertools` `islice` and `cycle`

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

df.assign(col1=[*islice(cycle(lst), len(df))])

   col1   col2
0  new1  test1
1  new2  test2
2  new3  test3
3  new4  test4
4  new5  test5
```

Comment: I got error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: I cant use the `More generically` because my columns are all different names, I simply used new as an example

Comment: @RustyShackleford sorry (-: it takes time to put all my ideas down.  You've got another option to try.

Comment: Itertools did it!

Answer (score 1):

One way from `numpy.put`

```
lst = ['new1','new2']
np.put(df['col1'],np.arange(len(df)),lst)
df
Out[37]: 
   col1   col2
0  new1  test1
1  new2  test2
2  new1  test3
3  new2  test4
4  new1  test5
```

---

Another option

```
n=len(df)
df['col1']=(lst*((n//len(lst))+1))[:n]
df
Out[48]: 
   col1   col2
0  new1  test1
1  new2  test2
2  new1  test3
3  new2  test4
4  new1  test5
```

Comment: This gave me `NoneType object`

Comment: @RustyShackleford Not sure  what happen in your real data , but this work for the sample data you provided .

Comment: @RustyShackleford try 2rd option ?